# Find Weekending Date (Friday) based on another Date column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, date

I am trying to replicate a weekending query that I use in access, in SQL Server and not having much luck with getting ti to perform how I need it to.

Basically, I need to find the week-ending date (with the week-ending date being a Friday) of another date column and would like it formatted to be American short date (eg. 10/06/2017).

I use the below in Access which gets me the result I need. So if the ACTUAL_DATE is 10/03/2017, the result I would need is 10/06/2017.

```
Actual_Date_WE: [ACTUAL_DATE] + 7 - Weekday([ACTUAL_DATE], 7)
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: mysql or sql server - pick one.

Comment: SQL server, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Declare @Date date
SET @Date = '2017-10-01'
select dateadd(day, (7+(6 - datepart(WEEKDAY, @date))) %7, @date)
```

Comment: To avoid issues with `@@DATEFIRST` not being 7 (e.g. in languages other than English, the default datefirst setting may be 1), I would suggest using `(20 - @@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @date)) % 7`

Comment: Thank you both! Worked a treat :)

Comment: Thank you ZLK, I guess this is even better as Datepart(Weekday...) is affect ed by the @@DATEFIRST. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @i date='10/3/2017'
declare @Friday int=6

SELECT convert(varchar,dateadd(day,(@Friday-DATEPART(dw,@i)),@i) ,110)
```